# How to compute the multiplicative order of an element in a finite field

Tags: list-manipulation, finite-fields

I want to find the multiplicative order of say the element {0,1,0} in GF[8].

I made a list:
b = Map[GF[8][#] &, Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]]
I tried:
NestWhileList[b[[3]]*# &, b[[3]], # != b[[5]] &]

But this doesn't return what I was expecting which is a list of all the powers of {0,1,0}.

Comment: How/where is `GF` defined?

Comment: FiniteFields` package symbol for Galois Field:  " GF[q] gives the Galois field with q elements, for q a prime power."

Comment: The FiniteFields package is woefully dated. Sorry.

Comment: @ Daniel Lichtblau.  What do you mean by "woefully dated".  Do I need to get another version of Mma?

Comment: Never saw the comment above (due to spaces I think). No, a new version won't help. It's the package itself that has been abandoned.